# Django Doesn't Serialize id of the model

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

I have a simple class :

```
class Item(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

I need to serialize it to JSON with the ID as part of the JSON, but the ID never gets serialized when called in the view:

```
items_json = serializers.serialize('json',  item_list)
```

The item_list json as received by the browser contains only name, not the ID.
I need the ID for the processing on the client side which returns to the server later.

1) I'd like to avoid creating another ID if possible

2) I haven't created a Serializer Class. I am not sure where and how to do that.

Comment: Yes it does include the primary key. You should show the content of `items_json` if you're sure it doesn't.

Comment: I am sure it doesn't because the json as I see it in the browser doesn't return it.:

{data: "[{"model": "portal.item", "pk": 1, "fields": {"name": "Test Item 1"}}]", result: "success",…}
data
:
"[{"model": "portal.item", "pk": 1, "fields": {"name": "Test Item 1"}}]"
not_permitted
:
"[{"model": "portal.item", "pk": 3, "fields": {"name": "Secrete"}}, {"model": "portal.item", "pk": 2, "fields": {"name": "Item Secret"}}]"
result
:
"success"

Comment: But I can see `"pk": 1` etc in that output.

Comment: Is pk the id? I guess it is. It was outside the fields list.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The pk field that is sent over is the id. The id will now show up in the fields. So in javascript you should do:

```
$.each( $.parseJSON(data), function(key, val) {
    console.log("ID: " + val.pk)
});
```